# Why is it illegal : copying vector of pointers into a vector of pointers to constants

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, vector, constants

## The issue

The following code does not compile in C++11 (nor C++14). I understand the error output from the compiler, but why isn't it allowed by the standard?

```
//main.cpp

#include <vector>

int main(void)
{
    double a = 3.0;
    double b = 3.0;

    //It works with mere pointers
    const double* ptrToConst = &a;
    /***/ double* ptrToObj   = &a;
//  ptrToObj = ptrToConst; //Illegal : that's understandable…
    ptrToConst = ptrToObj;   //Works

    //But the same doesn't work with vectors to pointers
    std::vector<const double*> ptrsToConst = {&a, &b};
    std::vector</***/ double*> ptrsToObj   = {&a, &b};
//  ptrsToObj = ptrsToConst; //Illegal : that's understandable
    ptrsToConst = ptrsToObj; //Illegal : but why?!
}
```

The error comes from the line `ptrsToConst = ptrsToObj`. Indeed, it does not seem possible to copy a vector of pointers `std::vector<T*>` into a vector of pointers to constants `std::vector<const T*>`. Note that in both cases, the pointers themselves are **not** constant.

Why would this operation be illegal?
What would be the most elegant work around?

---

## Further details

If I compile by invoking `clang++ --std=c++11 main.cpp`,  the following error message displays:

```
main.cpp:19:17: error: no viable overloaded '='
    ptrsToConst = ptrsToObj; //Illegal : but why?!
    ~~~~~~~~~~~ ^ ~~~~~~~~~
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/stl_vector.h:436:7: note: candidate
      function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector<double *, allocator<double *>>' to 'const
      vector<const double *, allocator<const double *>>' for 1st argument
      operator=(const vector& __x);
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/stl_vector.h:448:7: note: candidate
      function not viable: no known conversion from 'vector<double *, allocator<double *>>' to 'vector<const
      double *, allocator<const double *>>' for 1st argument
      operator=(vector&& __x) noexcept(_Alloc_traits::_S_nothrow_move())
      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5.4.0/../../../../include/c++/5.4.0/bits/stl_vector.h:470:7: note: candidate
      function not viable: no known conversion from 'std::vector<double *>' to 'initializer_list<value_type>' (aka
      'initializer_list<const double *>') for 1st argument
      operator=(initializer_list<value_type> __l)
      ^
1 error generated.
```

Trying the same with gcc (g++) spawns similar error messages.

Apparently, the way vectors are implemented does not allow for the operation I am trying to perform. However that is a safe operation regarding const correctness, right?

Comment: `std::vector<const double*>` is not a cv qualified version of `std::vector<double>`

Comment: `std::vector<const double*>` and `std::vector<double>` are completely different and unrelated types. Especially since you can't guarantee that neither of both is a special implementation of the template class.

Comment: An elegant solution might be to store your elements in a `std::vector` and then use `const` iterators when you don't want to change the data.

Comment: You just can't assign a `std::vector<T>` to a `std::vector<U>` if `T` and `U` are different types, regardless of the relationship between `T` and `U`. I guess the designer of `std::vector` did not consider this usage.

Comment: @imreal  indeed `std::vector<const double*>` is a vector type that allows (for instance) inserting/appending a new member. However that new member will be stored "internally" as a `const double*`, which means it either must be a `const double*` or another type that can be converted to it, such as `double*` for instance.

Comment: @Muscampester: If you used const iterators over `std::vector<double*>`, it would leave you with const access to a bunch of pointers to non-const doubles. Equivalent to if you had a `std::vector<double* const>` (if such a thing were possible), not equivalent to `std::vector<const double*>`.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I meant more simplification than that; `std::vector<double> doubles{3.0,3.0};` with `auto itrToConst = doubles.cbegin();` and `auto itrToObj = doubles.begin();` for example.

Comment: @Muscampester: You know the difference between `double const*` and `double *const` ?  OP wants the first and your suggested solution is the second, which is not at all the same.

Comment: @BenVoigt I suggested the first. [Here is an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/991db1d163c6f8bc). An iterator equivalent to `double *const` doesn't seem very useful.

Comment: @Muscampester: Your example doesn't store pointers, so you entirely missed the difference.  The iterator type would be similar to `double const**` vs `double* const*`.  Not the same.

Comment: @BenVoigt I never mentioned `double const**` vs `double* const*`. Why should the example store pointers? I'm still baffled by the comment that states that I suggested something similar to `double *const`.

Comment: @Muscampester: Go back and read the question, the data inside the vector is a pointer (`double*`).  Then you have an iterator to that (effectively, double pointer).

Comment: @BenVoigt The question shows a `vector` of pointers. Your answer deals with `vector`s of pointers. All good. My comment was merely a that the values could rather be stored in a `vector` of values to begin with, and then the relevant iterators could be used. Of course, if the variables are scattered then a `vector` of values might not make sense and then we're back to the more complicated, but perhaps necessary `vector` of pointers.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can do this, just not with `operator=`.  You need the `assign` member function, which performs the conversion on each individual element.

```
ptrsToConst.assign(ptrsToObj.begin(), ptrsToObj.end());
```

Comment: Maybe you want to add that this overrides the content of the const vector with copies from the non-const vector. And that it won't work with reference assignment.

Comment: @BenVoigt Is copying `std::vector<T*>` to `std::vector<const T*>` a normal process? Or rather `assign` function is just a workaround for an unusual copy process that is not recommended in c++? I am concerned about the efficiency and the speed of `assign()`

Comment: @Admia: `assign` is used when an element-wise conversion is necessary.  It's templated, so it will be extremely efficient/fast.

Comment: Really the only efficiency concern would be if `assign` couldn't preallocate, but normally the library will check for a random-access iterator where the length is available in advance (like it is here).  If you were using a forward iterator, then repeated allocation could happen -- and I expect that you could then provide a hint about the size via the `reserve()` member function.  But the library should be smart enough to get the size in advance for this random-access iterator.

Comment: `assign` is required to pre-allocate for all forward-and-better iterators. Only for input-only iterators (which may be single-pass) is it allowed to reallocate.

Answer (score 4):

Because it is the way `std::vector` is implemented: the assignement operator requires the other operand to be of same type. And `vector<double *>` and `vector<const double *>` are different type because `double` and `const double` are different even if compatible types.

One could imagine to relax that requirement only to compatible types but it would be more complex to implement, when the implementation of standard containers is already complex enough (just read the vector header once...), and neither the writers of the library nor the standard comittee found it necessary.

If you really need it, you will have to write a custom implementation...

Answer (score -2):

I am not sure, but maybe c++ copies `std::vector<T*>` object to `std::vector<const T*>` object by reference. That means c++ does not allocate new memory for new constructed object of `std::vector<const T*>`. This new constructed object of `std::vector<const T*>` would be another name (or reference) for the old object of `std::vector<T*>`. Then, it makes sense why an error is raised. Because object of `std::vector<T*>` can alter what it is pointing to, however object of `std::vector<const T*>` cannot alter what it is pointing to.

Comment: No, it does not do this.